# When/why do Jedi and Sith say "destroy" instead of "kill"?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, sith, language-explanation

In *Return of the Jedi*, Luke says to Vader:

> That was why you couldn't destroy me. That's why you won't take me to your emperor now.

Later, the Emperor says to Luke:

> If you will not be turned, you will be **destroyed**.

And in The Phantom Menace, Mace Windu says with regard to the apparent death of Darth Maul:

> But which was **destroyed**? The master, or the apprentice?

Perhaps most famously (as @Adamant reminded me), Vader in *The Empire Strikes Back*:

> There is no escape. Don't make me **destroy** you.

And later in the same fight:

> Luke, you can **destroy** the Emperor. He has foreseen this!

That's enough to establish a pattern. Why do these characters consistently say "destroy" instead of "kill"? It is just a peculiar force-user mannerism/tradition, or is there some underlying spiritual significance to their choice of words? Am I correct in my presumption that this pattern is exclusive or nearly exclusive to force-users?

Note that there are several places in the scripts where the word "destroy" is used where "kill" would not be a suitable replacement, for example when discussing the destruction of a planet, a ship, or a droid (it's not obvious whether droids are alive to begin with). Those usages of the word "destroy" are not relevant to the question.

I am also aware that there are occurrences of force-users *not* using the word destroy, such as when Obi-Wan tells Luke that Vader "betrayed and **murdered** [his] father." That doesn't invalidate the question unless someone can prove that the usages of "destroy" noted above are not statistically significant.

Edit: if there's a simple out-of-universe explanation such as censorship, that's a valid answer as long as it can be backed up by specific evidence. However, I am skeptical of this due to several uncensored usages of the word "kill" in those same movies:

Episode IV:

Vader:

> Send a distress signal, and then inform the senate that all aboard were **killed**!

Obi-Wan:

> You'd have been **killed**, too, and the droids would be in the hands of the Empire.

Luke:

> But they're going to **kill** her!

Episode V:

Lando:

> If you put him in there, it might **kill** him.

Luke:

> He told me enough!  He told me you **killed** him!

Episode VI:

> I can't **kill** my own father.

> I will not turn... and you'll be forced to **kill** me.

And perhaps most perplexing/telling of all:

> You couldn't bring yourself to **kill** me before, and I don't believe you'll **destroy** me now.

It seems as if characters are more likely to use "destroy" instead of "kill" when the person being destroyed and/or killed is a force user. But even if that's correct, it doesn't explain *why* they use this language.

Comment: Don't make me destroy you.

Comment: Force users are nothing if not dramatic.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the reason is censorship. Shows written for children usually avoid using certain words completely, and one of those words is often "kill." https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NeverSayDie

Comment: Palpatine tells Anakin "kill him" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBTwFvMSYhg

Comment: @Kai q.v. "*younglings*"

Comment: Obi-Wan came back to advise Luke, Palpatine returned to do whatever he did in the last movie, I'm not going to look it up, and Legends is positively rife with Force-users outliving their mortal forms. Where the Force is concerned, killing is not enough.

Comment: @Cadence Are you suggesting that "destroy" is meant to be interpreted as "destroy **the body** (but not the soul/spirit/whatever aspect of a person goes on to become a force ghost)" ?

Comment: I was thinking of the usage the other way around - kill the body, or destroy the whole person, body and spirit. But that's mostly me thinking of Vitiate in *The Old Republic*, who very definitely needed to be *destroyed* and not merely "killed".

Comment: Probably Broadcast Standards banning the use of "kill" in a movie aimed at children. This censorship did not go unnoticed in the 90s X-Men cartoon, and the repeated use of "destroyed" instead of "killed" is still being mocked to this day. (Like @Kai said above.)

Comment: Might not have to always mean 'killing' Vader likes to say he destroyed Anakin as an edgy metaphor, mentally breaking someone until they become an Inquisitor might be considered destroying them too.

Comment: Very interesting question! I've never realized that.

Comment: LOL  I'll see you a Vitiate, and match it with Sion.  Sion, as shown in the game: had a healing factor to comeback from: explosions, repeatedly be force lightningined, kicked out of an air lock, stabbed many times after baning a twlik worker. And probably even a decapition from a former teacher.  And then he met a jedi check who he had a crush for, on sight, and just say wanted to bone reely badly.  So yeah "Destroy" or Obliterate was the way to go IIRC

Comment: I took it to imply a crushing defeat. Keep in mind the original movies were a product of a deranged writer, and his wife from the 70s. Their slang included: "cat" to meen a person, "Wild up" to implying beyond high,  and "just crazy man" I think that was the best they could do for "I just can't"

Answer (score 4):

I think that by using the word "destroy", the Force users (both light and dark) imply that they mean the physical body, while the spirit may be preserved (as a Force Ghost for a Jedi, or as a detached spirit for a Sith; the latter may find him/herself a new body later).

It could also be some dramatization, and/or high language.

Comment: I think this is probably right, or destroy both physical body and connection to the Force, but is there any evidence to back this up?